# Which one to choose: Hadoop custom jars, Hadoop Streaming, Pig, or Mahout?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, mahout, hadoop-streaming

I am working on an NLP project that can create entity sets and compute pairwise similarity from large-scale corpora. Currently I am using **hadoop streaming** and have implemented all the mappers and reducers in **Python**. Since the algorithm needs several rounds of map-reduce, I use Shell scripts to chain the jobs.

Now here are my concerns and what I want to do next:

- **[Concern 1]. Job chaining and job controls**. Chaining hadoop streaming jobs is problematic. If job2 in the job sequence (job1-job2-job3) failed, I have to manually delete the output folder, adjust the script file that launches the jobs and re-run the job sequence from the middle. I really hope to find a smarter way to do this. As I need to frequently adjust the parameters and the logic of the algorithms, I don't want to repeat those steps again and again.
- **[Concern 2]. Speed and efficiency**. I think a great proportion of the time costs is for parsing the text into numbers and such kind of format-conversion processes which are totally unnecessary. It takes a lot to time to type and test those near-duplicate Python codes during development, too.
- **[Concern 3]. Easiness to maintain and distribute**. As the project is getting big (I am having more than 20 map-reduce jobs), it really needs to modularize the whole project. I want to make it object-oriented, and use IDE to develop and maintain the project, so that it would be more comfortable handling the various internal data structure and format. And also I want  to distribute my project as a package, so that other people may benefit from it. I need an easy way to import the whole project in an IDE and make it easy to distribute.

I've done some research on the possibilities of solutions:

- **Alternative 1. Hadoop custom jars**: It seems that the best way to do this is to convert the entire project into java - a hadoop custom jar. This may fix all the problems, including job chaining, efficiency and maintenance issue. But it may take quite much time, and I have found a way to do efficient debugging.
- **Alternative 2. Pig**: I found the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873077/streaming-or-custom-jar-in-hadoop) to be quite helpful in figuring out when to (not) use pig. In the answer, Arun_suresh says if "you have some very specific computation you need to do within your Map/reduce functions … then you should consider deploying your own jars". My job includes shingling, hashing, min-hashing, permutation, etc. Can it be implemented using Pig Latin? Is there a place that I can get an idea about how complex computations can Pig Latin programs have?
- **Alternative 3. Mahout**: I found that the newly released [Apache Mahout](http://mahout.apache.org/) versions has several functions that overlap with what I am doing, but it cannot replace my work. Shall I base my project on Mahout?

Since I am basically on my own to do this job, and only have about 2 weeks' time budget to do the whole housekeeping work, and about 1 month to improve it, I really need to find an efficient and reliable way to do it. Please help me choose one of the alternatives or tell me if you have a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Concern 1: Look into using OOZIE, you can define the entire job chain in a 'workflow', with a number of actions (they can be Map reduce steps, decision switches / joins).

  Each action can define a prepare stage where you can delete the upcoming output folder.

  You are also able to see where in the workflow failure occured, and re-run the workflow from that particular step.

  The OOZIE documentation has examples of running [streaming](http://incubator.apache.org/oozie/docs/3.2.0-incubating/docs/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.2.2.2_Streaming) jobs, and some [cookbook examples too (Case 7)](http://incubator.apache.org/oozie/map-reduce-cookbook.html)
- Concern 2: This is a problem shared by all streaming jobs, if you want the best performance you'll either need to bite the Java bullet, or seek alternative stream input / output formats that can handle binary formats (such as AVRO), and you'll need some custom mapper / reducers stream wrappers that know how to handle these.
- Concern 3: With streaming, you can bundle all the python scripts into a tarball, and have hadoop unpack the tarball to every task node. This is a function of the DistributedCache archives feature (in OOZIE this is defined in the archives element of the map-reduce action - see Case 6 in the previous OOZIE cookbook link)